# Get user email from Facebook SDK android

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am just starting out with the Facebook SDK, I currently have an app that has its own login system, the user enters their email and password and then the app checks a mysql database to find the user. 
If the user is their it returns the user info and logs them into the app.

What I am trying to do is allow the user to just press a Facebook button and have the Facebook SDK return the users email linked to their Facebook account. 
Then I can search my database for that email and log the user in or create an account for them if their is no account with that email.

I have everything set up apart from having the Facebook SDK actually return the email for the user. I am not sure where to start with this and could really use some help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two options to get the email of the Facebook user:

#### Option 1: Use Facebook SDK

1. Implement [**Facebook Login**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/authenticate/) with `email` permission
2. Get the user data by using `Request.newMeRequest()`. This is explained here: [**Personalize**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/personalize/)

#### Oprion 2: Use Simple Facebook SDK library

The library: https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook

1. Set `email` permission by using `Permissions.EMAIL`
2. Then, login

   ```
   mSimpleFacebook.login(MainActivity.this);
   ```
3. And then, get the profile with the `email`

   ```
   mSimpleFacebook.getProfile(new OnProfileRequestAdapter()
   {
       @Override
       public void onComplete(Profile profile)
       {
           String id = profile.getId();
           String firstName = profile.getFirstName();
           String email = profile.getEmail();
           // ... and many more properties of profile ...
       }
   });
   ```