# How can I get informations to register from facebook?

Tags: android, android-facebook

I want to people sign in my app to use facebook login, But how can I get ;
*name
*lastname
*email
*male/female
*birthday

informations? Is it possible?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes.Use Facebook SDK 3.0 and facebook provides api to extract name,email,birthday etc.,based
  on your requirement. See this tutorial.Hope this helps.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/

Comment: but in that link , there is a json sample data , and there is no email data , is it right?

Comment: no..everything is provided by facebook api. just use and check it. it has api for email.  String email = profile.getString("email"); just check in log by using that.  Log.d("Profile", response); you can see what are all response you can use. @user3086226

Comment: check your facebook sdk.structure alone looks same.that means you want to do some surf like checking latest sdk too. here everything is provided as for profile, you want to check for email permissions. @user3086226 see for more details too..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701954/get-user-email-from-facebook-sdk-android